# VS Code doesn't recognise "using UnityEngine" as a valid namespace. What can I do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I opened the ".cs" file from Unity after creating a C# file in my project, however
[neither UnityEngine nor (obviously) MonoBehaviour is detected in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhcKO.png).
Due to this, Intellisense also can't help, which is a major obsticle for me, because I am completely new to the UnityEngine library. The OmniSharp log also gives a
warning in the output:

```
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\bomka\My project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.InlayHints.InlayHintService
        Inlay hints requested for document not in workspace Location { FileName = c:\Users\bomka\My project\Assets\scripts\Circle.cs, Range = Range { Start = Point { Line = 0, Column = 0 }, End = Point { Line = 19, Column = 0 } } }
```

Things I've tried so far:

- I've redownloaded both Unity and VS Code (latest versions, which are 2021.3.3f1 and 1.67.2, respectively)
- I checked whether Visual Studio Code Editor and Visual Studio Editor were downloaded in Unity's Package Library (they are, it's 1.2.5 and and 2.0.15, respectively)
- I changed `omnisharp.path` to "latest" in VS Code because I've read it resolved the "Attempted to update project..." issue. It didn't really do anything unfortunately

Does anyone have any ideas concerning what I should do here? Another useful piece of information is that this is my first ever Unity Project and so VS Code didn't just decide to malfunction after a while, this is how it's been behaving since I started writing my first piece of code for my project.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you gone through [Unity Development with VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) to set up your environment?

Comment: I think you haven't included the tooling required. Also i can really recommend jet brains' [rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) This IDE works really well with unity

Comment: @NightOwl888 I downloaded the .NET package, and followed the instructions concerning the set-up, but it didn't help unfortunately. VS recommended me some packages, so now I'm downloading those aswell. fingers crossed...

Comment: @rbdeenk what do you exactly mean by tooling required?

Comment: @Floof If you are using visual studio code. I would suggest trying a different IDE like visual studio or rider. Visual studio is one of if not te best C# IDE, both of these have built in extensions for unity (you have to enable these when installing).

Comment: if you insist on using VS Code have you looked at [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) article

Answer (score 1):

Delete all .csproj files on the project's root.

Then edit->preferences->external tools-> Regenerate project files.

On VSCode F1->Reload Window

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is VS set in your external tools in Unity?

Edit > Pref > External Tools > External (Script) Editor : Visual Studio..

Not sure if it'll help but I know the above will fix Intellisense issues so it might be worth a shot.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, but it I've done it already and it didn't help sadly